# Firefox OS Certified apps

Tags: mobile, sms, firefox-os

I have downloaded and installed FIrefox OS Simulator for testing and developing. I want to test some functionalities that are allowed only on certified applications, such as SMS and phone calling, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/App_permissions).

What should I include in my manifest (.webapp file) in order to access this functionality in the simulator?

Thanks,
Tamas Ionut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very manual, but I think it'll is cool to understand how stuff work under the hood (and it's the only way I know it'll always work):

1. Be sure your `manifest.webapp` includes `"type": "certified"`
2. Pack the app
3. Add the directory containing your `manifest.webapp` and the `zip` package to the simulator's Gais `webapps` directory
4. Add an entry on `webapps.json` for your app. Be sure it has `"appstatus": 3`
5. Have fun :)

The `webapps` directory of your simulator's Gaia should be in your Firefox profile, on a path like this:

```
/home/username/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/foobarbaz.default/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/profile/webapps/.
```

---

Now the easiest, but not currently that easy, way:

MDN has [an entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/Packaged_apps) that says

> Note: If you want to test certified app APIs (described above), turn on "developer mode" on the device you want to install the app on (Firefox OS) and make sure to specify the correct type in your manifest.webapp file.

I've seen that option on Simulator, but it has gone recently. I can barely recall seeing somewhere someone saying that they would disable some flags for the Simulator build, but as I can't find it anymore. Anyway, you could try two options:

1. building the Simulator yourself (I'll require tons of space and time, be aware!) and see if you can get this option there. It's not likely it'll work, if it was really disabled though
2. Download Simulator 1.1pre2 ou 1.1pre3 from [labs ftp](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/r2d2b2g/), the last Simulator build I'm aware that had that option enabled.

Comment: Just curious: what path did you follow?

Comment: Setting the "developer mode" on the 1.1 Simulator version still returns null when trying to get mozSMS for example. However, the API is not completely defined and I believe that some problems such as this one appear because of that. If you manage to intercept SMS and/or phone calls in the simulator using a background service, please post another comment here.

Comment: I don't remember doing that on 1.1, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the standard [sms](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/master/apps/sms) and [dialer](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/master/apps/communications) apps.

Keep in mind though that the production builds of Firefox OS will not allow the installation of third-party certified apps.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the official source for your answer so I can verify for myself? Thanks..

Comment: It was stated by Panagiotis Astithas ([@pastith](https://twitter.com/pastith)) during the Firefox OS App Day in Athens, Greece.

Comment: So far, I am not interested in production builds. I only need to simulate certain functionalities (e.g. SMS interception, phone call interception, etc.) that are available only in certified apps. I've tried putting "type": "certified" in the .webapp file but the mozSms for example, is null. How must I configure the manifest for accessing mozSms functionality?