# How to certify Firefox OS 1.4 app?

Tags: firefox-os

I am developing Firefox OS 1.4 app. It is just a basic app. All it does is fetch file from SD card.

But the problem is only certified app can have this authority. And I am planing to make more such type of apps in future. So the problem is every time my app will not run because it is not a certified app.

Now I googled a lot to find how to certify Firefox OS 1.4 app. While searching on this site I found only one [question similar to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136765/firefox-os-certified-apps).

According to first answer I have `mainfest.webapp` including `"type": "certified"`. And then I zipped all files (not folder). I have following files:

1. mainfest.webapp
2. index.html
3. MyJavaScript.js

But I do not know what is `webapps.json` file and how to add `"appstatus": 3` to it.

I have ordered real Firefox OS 1.4 phone from flipkart (it is not yet come) and I want to run my apps on my real Firefox OS 1.4 phone. All I want to do is certify my app so that it can be authorized to do secure tasks. Please help me and tell me the way I can certify my Firefox OS 1.4 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Certified app is generally an internal app and it comes along with the device. Third party developers cannot create or distribute such apps. I think you are trying to develop a privileged app. Privileged app can access the sdcard upon user prompt. Mention the app type as privileged in manifest file and submit the app to the Firefox OS marketplace for code review if you wish to distribute it through marketplace.

Comment: That's right. But you should be aware that Mozilla stopped working on Firefox OS for smartphones. There is a B2G community project to carry it on (see https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Transition_Project/FAQ). But, in any case, the concept of Firefox OS apps is going to disappear. The Firefox OS Marketplace should also disappear, and there's already nobody left to review the apps you might submit on it (at least for privileged apps). In other words, don't expect your new privileged app to end up on it.